# Nuxt3 + module federation

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I'm trying to test module federation with Nuxt 3, but I'm facing some problems.

#### Current setup

I'm using docker containers to test locally.

##### Remote Library

I'm trying to use one of [webpack module federation examples](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples), i.e. [`vue3-demo /home/`](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/vue3-demo/home), as a remote library exposed on `localhost:3002` via `npm run serve` (from its own folder) and import/use its exposed `Button` component in my custom spa.
(This app is run in a single node:20 container)

##### My SPA

I'm currently using a simple test spa made with Nuxt 3, the app is statically built via `npm run generate` with `ssr: false` and exposed by nginx on `localhost`.
(for this i'm using a node:20 container to build and an nginx container to serve)

Looking at the counterpart example for the remote library ([`vue3-demo /layout/`](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/vue3-demo/layout)), I installed `webpack` package and updated my spa `nuxt.config.ts` this way:

```js
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;

export default defineNuxtConfig({

  webpack: {
    plugins: [
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: 'layout',
        filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
        remotes: {
          home: 'home@http://localhost:3002/remoteEntry.js',
        },
        exposes: {},
        shared: {
          vue: {
            singleton: true,
          },
        },
      }),
    ],
  }
})
```

and the spa still build with no error.

Then I updated one of the component (i.e. `components/header.vue`) trying to include the exposed `Button` component from the lybrary:

```js
<script setup>
import { defineAsyncComponent } from "vue";

const RemoteButton = defineAsyncComponent(() => import("home/Button"));
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();
nuxtApp.component("remote-button", RemoteButton);
</script>
```

Trying to build now i get an error.

##### The build error

```
> generate
> nuxt generate


 WARN  Changing NODE_ENV from development to production, to avoid unintended behavior.                                    7:49:49 AM

Nuxt 3.7.4 with Nitro 2.6.3                                                                                               7:49:50 AM
ℹ Building client...                                                                                                     7:49:53 AM
ℹ vite v4.4.9 building for production...                                                                                 7:49:53 AM
transforming (115) node_modules/@nuxt/ui-templates/dist/templates/error-dev.vueCould not resolve id home/Button /home/node/app/components/header.vue                                                     7:49:54 AM
Could not resolve id home/Button /home/node/app/components/header.vue                                                     7:49:54 AM
ℹ ✓ 119 modules transformed.                                                                                             7:49:54 AM
ℹ ✓ built in 1.16s                                                                                                       7:49:54 AM

 ERROR  [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "home/Button" from "/home/node/app/components/header.vue".                7:49:54 AM
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
build.rollupOptions.external


[7:49:54 AM]  ERROR  Nuxt Build Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "home/Button" from "/home/node/app/components/header.vue".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
build.rollupOptions.external

  This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
  If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
  build.rollupOptions.external
  at viteWarn (node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:48142:27)
  at onRollupWarning (node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:48174:9)
  at onwarn (node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-df561101.js:47902:13)
  at node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24276:13
  at Object.logger [as onLog] (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:25950:9)
  at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24862:26)
  at ModuleLoader.resolveDynamicImport (node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24920:58)
  at async node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24807:32
```

## Update #1

Added following code to `nuxt.config.ts`:

```js
  vite: {
    build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        external: 'home/Button'
      }
    },
  }
```

Now spa build correctly (i.e. no error during `npm run generate`) but now I get following error in browser console:
[image]

[image]

Comment: it would be more helpful if you turn off the minification while doing such research thing so you have the original variable name for better debugging experience

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the build-tool is still `vite` while your configuration does not contain vite, and you should configure with `builder: 'webpack',`.
But on the other hand, when I configured  `builder: 'webpack'`, there will be kinds of errors, and I think it is bugs of npm package `@nuxt/webpack-builder`.
[you build error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Qi5N.png)